# Element's opacity change when scrolled on point

Tags: javascript, jquery

So basically I want my #header (which has fixed position) change his opacity to 0.5 when user is on 400px height of the page for example. If it's before 400px and the mouse is over #header - change opacity to 1.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#header:hover { opacity:1; } //CSS for mouse over #header

// javascript
var head = document.getElementById("header");
if (document.body.scrollTop > 400) 
    head.setAttribute("style","opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50)");
else
    head.setAttribute("style","opacity:1; -moz-opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100)");
```